# Order statistics for exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stopping-times, order-statistics

Let $\tau_1, \tau_2, ..., \tau_K$ be i.i.d. exponential random variables with distribution $P(\tau_k<t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$. Let $\tau^*_i$ be the $i^{th}$ order statistic. The p.d.f. of $\tau^*_i$ can be found in standard textbook:
$$ f_{\tau_i^*}(t) = K{K-1 \choose i-1} f_{\tau}(t) (F_{\tau}(t))^{i-1}(1-F_{\tau}(t))^{k-i}$$

In my previous lecture, my professor was interested in computing the probability:
$$ P(\tau_1^* = \tau_j \in [a,b))$$
for every $i \in \{1,...,K\}$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{R_+}$.

There is clearly some abuse of notation here since the event ${\tau_1^* = \tau_j}$ never happens almost surely. However he claims this notation is intuitive in some sense. He then writes that: 
$$ P(\tau_1^* = \tau_j \in [a,b)) = \int_{a}^{b} \lambda_j e^{-\lambda_j t} \prod_{i \neq j} e^{-\lambda_i t} dt$$

and if we have i.i.d. condition then:

$$ P(\tau_1^* = \tau_j \in [a,b)) = \int_{a}^{b} \lambda e^{-K \lambda t} dt$$
If we use the standard result from above for the p.d.f. of $\tau_1^*$, we get:

$$ f_{\tau_1^*}(t) = {K \choose 1} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} (1 - e^{-\lambda t})(e^{-\lambda t})^{K-1}$$
So we should have that:
$$P(\tau_1^*\in [a,b))=\int_{a}^{b}{K \choose 1} \lambda e^{-\lambda t} (1 - e^{-\lambda t})(e^{-\lambda t})^{K-1}dt = \int_{a}^{b}K\lambda e^{-K\lambda t} (1 - e^{-\lambda t})dt$$

Why are these probabilities not equal? When considering the first order statistic, what does the event $\{\tau_1^* = \tau_j \in [a,b)\}$ mean?

Comment: Your formula for the density of $\tau_i^*$ is not quite right. It should read $K{K-1\choose i-1}f_\tau(t)[F_\tau(t)]^{i-1}[1-F_\tau(t)]^{k-i}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event in question is the event that the $j^{\rm th}$ sample point is the minimum and that it happens to fall in the interval $[a,b)$. By symmetry, the probability of this event is
$$
\eqalign{
{1\over K}P(\tau_1^*\in[a,b))
&={1\over K}\int_a^b Kf_\tau(t)[1-F_\tau(t)]^{K-1}\,dt\cr
&={1\over K}\int_a^b K \lambda e^{-\lambda t}[e^{-\lambda t}]^{K-1}\,dt\cr
&=\int_a^b  \lambda e^{-\lambda Kt}\,dt\cr
&={e^{-\lambda Ka}-e^{-\lambda Kb}\over K}.\cr
}
$$
This answer is the same as would be found by using your instructor's method.

Comment: This is definitely correct, but I don't see why you have a factor of $1/K$ everywhere?

Comment: @John Dawkins Also, I'm wondering, is there an intuitive way to see this? I'm not really see it. Thanks.

Comment: @probablyme What I think: Note that $\tau_1^*$ takes values in ${\tau_1, \tau_2,..., \tau_K}$.Since each $\tau_i$ is i.i.d., the probability that $\tau_1^*$ = $\tau_i$ is $1/K$ for every i. Therefore, $P(\tau_1 = \tau_j \in (a,b)) = 1/K * P(\tau_1^* \in (a,b)$.

Comment: @Pii: Yes, that was my reasoning "by symmetry".

Comment: @John Dawkins Could this symmetric argument be extended to $\tau_2^*$. In particular, does $P(\tau_2^* = \tau_i \in [a,b)) = (1/K)P(\tau_2^* \in [a,b))$?

Comment: Yes, and to the others as well.